# Ошибки в css-коде

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

У меня возникла ошибка при сохранении файла css. Не могу понять, почему Дримвьювер выдает в этом коде ошибку?

```
.connect{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 16px;
  color:#ff1818;

 border: 1px solid #ff1818;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    &:before{
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        widht: 0%; height: 100%;
        top: 0; left: auto; right: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        transition: all 2s ease;
    }
    &:hover{
        color: white;
        box-shadow: none;
        &:before{
            position: absolute;
            content: '';
            width: 100%; height: 100%;
            background: red;
            top: 0; left:0; right:0;
            z-index: -1

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Опечатка, не `widht` а `width`. Используйте более удобные редакторы или настройте свой нынешний, тогда и таких впоросов не будет.

Comment: У меня ошибку выдает перед &.

Comment: Так а Вы компилируете? Это же не `css`, это `scss`